# Can a project be a PhD research?

Tags: phd, thesis, projects, project-design

I am preparing PhD porposal
the proposal itself is a project design plan.

Is that possible for a Project to be a PhD research?

My Project is about web portal from data science.

Comment: There is too little information in your question to really give an answer. What field? What sort of project -- more than the last sentence. A thesis isn't normally about implementation, though it could be based on an implementation. Something that can be shown to be an improvement over current best practice, for example. But it is the proof, not the implementation that forms the key to the thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "project" sounds like an implementation of something. A thesis isn't normally about implementation, though it could be based on an implementation. Something that can be shown to be an improvement over current best practice, for example. But it is the proof, not the implementation that forms the key to the thesis.

For example, in Computer Science, a thesis often *starts with* a project. Suppose, for example, that you build a more efficient Garbage Collector for a runtime programming system than any currently known. That implementation isn't the thesis. You need to prove, somehow, that it is *indeed* more efficient and show the benchmarks. That proof is what makes it research and results in the thesis. But the program you write (the garbage collector) isn't the thesis.

Think of dissertation research as being about *knowledge*. After the proof is given we *know* something that we didn't know before. Building stuff isn't, per se, about knowledge.

Caveat: I will edit this if more information from OP makes it advisable.